# problem installing ComplexHeatmap. ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cluster’

Tags: r, r-package

i am installing an R package called complex heatmaps (https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/). I get this error. So far i just identified it might be do to this package : https://packages.debian.org/buster/r-cran-cluster but i am not sure what to do at all. Thats why i am writing you.
Thanks a lot for your help

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'cluster.so' failed
make: *** [cluster.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cluster’
* removing ‘/home/luca/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/cluster’
Error: Failed to install 'ComplexHeatmap' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘cluster’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are missing `libfortran.so`. You might even miss more tools necessary for installing R packages from source. How to install this depends on the Linux distribution you are using. For Debian, which you mention in the question, this would be

```
sudo apt install r-base-dev
```

If you want to speed up package installation, you can also use the binary packages available in Debian, i.e.

```
sudo apt install r-cran-cluster
```

Comment: Thank you very much! after running these commants i got some errors due to lock files that i solved with this post. https://itsfoss.com/could-not-get-lock-error/ . then i rerun your commands and it was possible to install the package.